# Alternative for preg_match_all in ereg

Tags: php, regex, text-extraction

I tried to get all the datas with a specific format (02:AA:13:09:45:DE)from a string using PHP (which may be stored in a CSV file) using the `ereg` function in PHP.

This is what I tried:

```
$string = '02:AA:13:09:45:DE -90 hRm / -21 450 s RX: 1.0 , 1 . TX: 2.0 , MCS 0, 1 . 13:09:13:10:15:5D -33 hRm / -55 5000 s RX: 66.0 , MCS 0, 333 . TX: 66.0, MCS 0, 333 . 17:09:A3:07:30:DC -55 hRm / -22 hRm 456 s RX: 43.0  MCS 0, 434. TX: 43.0 , MCS 0, 43 .'

$pattern='^[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}';
ereg($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This was giving only the first value: `02:AA:13:09:45:DE`. **As I should not use `preg_match_all`** (or any other `preg` functions), is there any other way to implement this (getting all thee datass)?

Comment: Why should you not use preg* functions?!

Comment: i am using php4 , that too in linux distro openwrt , where it was not at all taking PCRE, and ereg was working proper

Comment: @deceze   Fatal error: Call to undefined function: preg_match_all() in test.php on line 49.   This is what I gets when I use preg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` is the best option, and ereg is [dead](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php).

So your alternatives are somehow dirty.

```
$items = explode(" ", $string);
foreach($items as $item) {
    $chunks = explode(":", $item);
    // check current item. If consist of 6 hex digits separated by :
    if (count($chunks) == 6) {
        $valid = TRUE;
        // all numbers must be hex!
        foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
            if (!ctype_xdigit($chunk)) {
                $valid = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($valid) {
            echo $item;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am using php4 in linux distro openwrt where I am not able to use preg functions ( PCRE), thats why I tried with ereg...   I also tried you code like this    $items=explode(" ",$string); print_r($items); and it gave the mac ids in an array in indexes 0,27 and 54...   and thus i got the mac ids,  but if there are more numbere of macids in the same format , what shall i do? or is there any other way

Comment: @user2723949 I have edited my answer, Check it again!